# gradle common code for multiproject build

Tags: gradle

I have some common class definitions for a multiproject build in folder buildSrc:

```
root
 build.gradle
 settings.gradle
 a/
   build.gradle
 b/
   build.gradle
 buildSrc/
   common.gradle
```

where
    **settings.gradle** says

```
include ':a', ':b'
```

**a/build.gradle**

```
project(":a") {
    task someTask(type: CommonTask) {
        println "Running some task"
    }
}
```

**buildSrc/common.gradle**

```
class CommonTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def someAction() {
        println "Running common task"
    }
}
```

According to docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html

> **buildSrc** project. Drop the source for your build classes into a
>   certain directory and Gradle automatically compiles them and includes
>   them in the classpath of your build script.

However when running `gradle build` I get an error:

> Could not find property 'CommonTask' on project ':a'.

So how can we have common class definitions for a multiproject build?

## Edit

Adding `apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/common.gradle"` to `project a` does not help

## Edit2

I put the file `common.gradle` to `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/Common.groovy`

and in the root projects' `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.gradle'
}
```

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'root'.
>   Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.gradle}] on root project 'root'.

## Edit 3

I have 2 files:

`buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/iggy/gradle/A.groovy`:

```
package com.iggy.gradle

String someA() {
    return "a"
}
```

`buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/iggy/gradle/B.groovy`:

```
package com.iggy.gradle

String someB() {
    String a = someA()
    return a
}
```

But I get an error: `Could not find method someA()`

Shouldn't methods from same package be resolved? Adding `@PackageScope` or `public` doesn't help. So how can one import a method from another groovy file?

Comment: Groovy classes should be defined in a .groovy file, under a package. Not in a common.gradle file.

Comment: And the structure of buildSrc must be the structure of a groovy project: source files under src/main/groovy.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, could you please comment on the second edit? Do I need it at all? And how can subprojects access this code?

Comment: You shouldn't put your own classes in org.gradle. Put them in org.iggy or something like that. And just import org.iggy.CommonTask in the build.gradle files that need to use this class. You don't need to add a dependency on org.gradle.

Comment: @JBNizet the problem with this approach is that then I'd have to know import paths for packages like `import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask`. I am trying to find where `exec` method is being included from for like 10 mins already. Btw, do you know where is it located?

Comment: In Project. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:exec%28groovy.lang.Closure%29

Comment: @JBNizet thanks again, probably one last question: could you please have a look at `Edit 3`?

Comment: Put your methods in a class. in A.groovy: `public class A { public static String someA() { ... }}`. And in B.groovy: `public class B { public static String someB() { return A.someA() }}`